# Moodle configurable reports: Total time a SCORM is open

Tags: sql, plugins, report, moodle, scorm

Im new to this and trying the **configurable reports** plugin in Moodle. I need to get stats like total time someone has opened each SCORM file I uploaded (who/when/how long in total). I tried the "Custom SQL" query function in the plugin settings with fixed codes (ad-hoc contributed reports) but none is working. Any help?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

For time spent on SCORM activities, scorm_scoes_track is often helpful.

You can use the timemodified values for elements like x.start.time, cmi.exit (cmi.core.exit for SCORM 1.2), etc. or use cmi.total_time (cmi.core.total_time for SCORM 1.2) to get the time spent for a particular attempt of a SCORM activity.

There are still normally many details/decisions to get the data needed - e.g. supporting multiple versions of SCORM, handling multiple attempts, when the SCORM package is configured to send data back to the LMS, etc. - also many views about what time is relevant or not - but usually that table is a helpful place to start.